# React useEffect doesn't update state after Mobx store value has changed in another component in refresh page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx-react

I want to set the Navbar component active item from the other components by using Mobx store. If the store change with an event in the components, useEffect will update the Navbar state. But if the store change in useEffect of the components, when app start for first time or page refresh in browser the useEffect in navbar doesn't update the state.

Components call order in Home component

```
const Home: React.FC<HomeProps> = ({ component }) => {
return (
  <>
    <NavBar />
    <ToastContainer />
    <Container component={component} />
    <About />
    <Contact />
    <Footer />
  </>
 );
};
```

useEffect in Navbar component

```
const store = useStore();
const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
setActiveItem(store.navbarInfo.activeComponent);
 }, [store.navbarInfo.activeComponent]);
```

useEffect in another components to change the store

```
  const store = useStore();
  useEffect(() => {
      store.navbarInfo.activeComponent = "Test";
  });
```

If I change the call order in the Home component and put the Navbar after Container, Navbar state will be update properly in first time and refresh page, but the Navbar component render twice!

```
const Home: React.FC<HomeProps> = ({ component }) => {
return (
  <>
    <ToastContainer />
    <Container component={component} />
    <NavBar />
    <About />
    <Contact />
    <Footer />
  </>
 );
};
```

[image]

So, what is the best practice in this case to update the state in a component when the store is changed in useEffect of another component?

Comment: You can use `useContext` hook for "app-wide" state values that can be accessed by all components (no matter how deep) https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: I am using useContext with Mobx in the app. But it doesn't work in refresh.